# Solaris libglib2.0-dev

Tags: solaris, midnight-commander, glib

I want to install mc-4.8.12 (Midnight Commander), but I get this error:

```
glib-2.0 not found or version too old (must be >= 2.12)
```

When I search Google for a solution, I see the package `libglib2.0-dev` is missing. However I can't find the package for Solaris 5.10 libglib2.0-dev. Is there any other package like libglib2.0-dev for Solaris?

Bizarrely glib2.0 exists in `/usr/local/include/glib-2.0` - is there any configuration I should adjust?

Comment: What package repository are you using? What package installer: pkgutil, pkcon, etc.

Comment: until now i still had no package repository. But i installed the OpenCSW and follow the guidance from your next post. That solved my Problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have sufficient privilege to install a package, you can use the OpenCSW repository. If you already have pkgutil (the OpenCSW package utility) you can get their latest version of Midnight Commander packaged for Solaris (4.8.11, as of 2014 Aug 11) with:

```
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil --install mc
```

If you aren't already using OpenCSW, you can get Midnight Commander with:

```
pkgadd -d http://get.opencsw.org/now
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -U
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i vim
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil --install mc
```

NB, this will download and install about 80 dependent packages in /opt/csw. [Here's the current OpenCSW startup procedure, with all the caveats](http://www.opencsw.org/manual/for-administrators/getting-started.html). I haven't tried it on a clean system in a while, but I don't think adding vim is absolutely necessary.